# Correctly use MongoDB composite primary key in $lookup pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, composite-primary-key

I have a collection with a composite primary key as such

```
_id: {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b'
}
```

Explaining the following query, reveals that it does a **COLLSCAN** and the index is not used

```
db.collection.find({'_id.a': '1', '_id.b': '2'}).explain()
```

Changing that query to the following, uses the **IDHACK** successfully.

```
db.collection.find({_id: {a: '1', b: '2'}}).explain()
```

The problem is that this doesn't seem to work if used in the pipeline of a `$lookup` in an aggregation.

This doesn't return any results:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'collection',
  let: {
    pid: '1',
    sid: '2',
  },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        _id: {
          a: '$$pid',
          b: '$$sid',
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  as: 'results',
},
```

while the format that is not using the index returns results as expected:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'collection',
  let: {
    pid: '1',
    sid: '2',
  },
  pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
            $and: [
              {
                $eq: [
                  '$_id.a', '$$pid',
                ],
              }, {
                $eq: [
                  '$_id.b', '$$sid',
                ],
              },
            ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  as: 'results',
},
```

So my question is, how can I modify the lookup pipeline in order to use the index of the composite primary key?

Comment: The default and unique index on the `_id` field is on the _entire_ field - not on the individual fields within the sub-document. You can, if needed, define additional index(es) on individual fields or a compound index. I think `$lookup` can use index defined on the fields of the _from_ collection (please refer MongoDB Manual or online posts).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be 2 parts to this question: Why don't both _id queries use  the index? and why don't both lookups return data?

##### Why isn't the index used for both queries?

When MongoDB compares two objects, the order of the fields matters.  This means that all of these could be stored in the same collection, and each _id value is unique:

```
{_id:{ a:'1',b:'2'}},
{_id:{ b:'2',a:'1'}},
{_id:{ a:'1',b:'2',c:'3'}},
{_id:{ a:'1',c:'3',b:'2'}},
{_id:{ c:'3',a:'1',b:'2'}}
```

When an index includes a field such as `{_id: 1}`, the entire value of the field is used when building the index keys.  Given the above documents, a query on `{"_id.a":'1'}` could not be serviced by the index on `{_id:1}`.

The query

```
db.collection.find({_id: {a: '1', b: '2'}})
```

would match only the first document in the above list, and since it is querying only on the whole `_id` field, it can be properly serviced by the index.

The query

```
db.collection.find({'_id.a': '1', '_id.b': '2'})
```

is matching on the values of fields in the subdocument contained in the `_id` field, not on the whole field, so it cannot be properly serviced by the index on `{_id:`}`
This query would match *every* document in the above list.

##### Why don't both lookups return data?

MongoDB query language and aggregation language are different.

One of those differences is the aggregation language expands variable values in strings while the query language does not.

It is a bit confusing sometimes because the query language is used inside of the `$match` aggregation stage, unless you use the `$expr` operator to enclose the aggregation expression.

This match stage is checking for a document whose `_id` field is exactly the document `{a: '$$pid', b: '$$sid'}`, (i.e. the `_id.a` field contains the string "$$pid", etc.)

```
{
      $match: {
        _id: {
          a: '$$pid',
          b: '$$sid',
        },
      },
    },
```

To use the variables, you would need to also use the `$expr` operator like in the other query.

```
{$lookup:{
    let: {pid:'1', sid:'2'},
    as:"lookedup",
    from:"collection",
    pipeline:[{
        $match:{
           $expr:{
               $eq:[ "$_id", {a:"$$pid", b:"$$sid"}]
           }
        }
    }]
}}
```